# How do I force Google Search to use the word I type with no "corrections"?

Tags: google-search, search-operators

Many of the acronyms or scientific words I punch into Google seem to be silently auto-corrected to something more usual, e.g. "MAPB agarose" is turned into "map agarose" without the

> ***Showing results for `"fixed" word`***
>   Search instead for `what I want`

associated with the usual auto-corrections as perhaps it thinks my term was highly likely wrong.

Can I force Google to take my word that I know how to spell (some words)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put + directly in front of the word or phrase. I use this all the time. For example

```
+"MAPB agarose"
```

**Note:** This is no longer true.

> The + operator has been replaced.
>   To search for an exact word or phrase, use double quotation marks: hacker "news"

So you just need the quotes now.

Comment: Ironically enough, this question is currently the top result for that search string.

Comment: The plus and the quotes are redundant in the above example.  To avoid the "correction" of _MAPB_ to _MAP_, simply use a + before the word, as _+mapb agarose_.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The `+` (plus) symbol is no longer supporte.

Answer (score 4):

Google has launched Verbatim search, which should be rolled out soon.

> Since then, we’ve received a lot of requests for a more deliberate way to tell Google to search using your exact terms. We’ve been listening, and starting today you’ll be able to do just that through verbatim search. **With the verbatim tool on, we’ll use the literal words you entered without making normal improvements such as**
>
> - making automatic spelling corrections
> - personalizing your search by using information such as sites you’ve visited before
> - including synonyms of your search terms (matching “car” when you search [automotive])
> - finding results that match similar terms to those in your query (finding results related to “floral delivery” when you search [flower
>     shops])
> - searching for words with the same stem like “running” when you’ve typed [run]
> - making some of your terms optional, like “circa” in [the scarecrow circa 1963]

Here's how you can enable Verbatim

[image: Enable verbatim.]

Answer (score 0):

Google Search just suggests you some words which are related to your search terms, they are generally **dictionary** terms or **grammar fixes**, it always searches for the terms you type in the search box but it also suggests you synonyms of that term. So unless and until you don't click on suggestions, it will search only for the terms you wanted to search.

Comment: Did you even try my provided example?  The entire first couple pages do not include "mapb" at all, only "map".  If I only search "mapb", it's not autocorrected, but with the other term, it is.

Comment: I did searched and then I answered.